# What does tilde (~) in java stack trace mean?

Tags: java, stack-trace

I noticed that before jar name in stack traces there are tilde characters right before an opening square bracket. They always occur from the top of stack trace to a certain depth. Even identical traces might have tildes ending at different depth of stack trace. What are these tildes denoting?

```
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.library.hibernate.Hibernate.saveWithTx(Hibernate.java:758) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.hibernate.Hibernate.saveWithTx(Hibernate.java:738) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.signatureservice.signingdevices.SigningDeviceManagerImpl.addVMacSigningDevice(SigningDeviceManagerImpl.java:421) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.adminui.model.VMACDevices.saveItem(VMACDevices.java:243) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.adminui.model.VMACDevices.saveItem(VMACDevices.java:21) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.adminui.model.SignatureServerDataProvider.handleSaveItem(SignatureServerDataProvider.java:630) ~[library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.adminui.panel.ManagementPanel.saveButtonClicked(ManagementPanel.java:231) [library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.library.adminui.form.ManagementForm$5.onSubmit(ManagementForm.java:302) [library-4.5.1.0.jar:4.5.1.0]
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1568) [wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:960) [wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:921) [wicket-1.4.17.jar:1.4.17]
```

I'm using logback for logging stack traces.

Comment: On first sight, it appears that it's saying that the `.java` file is found in the specified `.jar` file.

Comment: @Justin You mean the `.class` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is non-standard behaviour.
The program you're running seems to be using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or another logger with similar formatting.

From the [Logback layout page](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#xThrowable) (emphasis mine):

> At the end of each stack frame of the exception, a string consisting of the jar file containing the relevant class followed by the "Implementation-Version" as found in that jar's manifest will be added. [...] **If the information is uncertain, then the class packaging data will be preceded by a tilde, i.e. the '~' character.**

> Logback goes to great lengths to ensure that the class packaging information it displays is correct [...]. However, when it is unable to guarantee the absolute correctness of the information, **then it will prefix the data with a tilde, i.e. the '~' character**. Thus, it is theoretically possible for the printed class packaging information to differ from the real class packaging information.

Almost identically, from the [Log4j layout page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout):

> At the end of each stack element of the exception, a string containing the name of the jar file that contains the class or the directory the class is located in and the "Implementation-Version" as found in that jar's manifest will be added. **If the information is uncertain, then the class packaging data will be preceded by a tilde, i.e. the '~' character.**

TL;DR: Tilde means "not 100% sure the class came from that jar".